# Забыл как называется технология чтобы определить DPI через HTTP запрос?

Tags: css, http

Читал недавно, она сырая, по-моему только хром поддерживает. То ли это какое то специфическое поле заголовка запроса, то ли что то ещё - забыл.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#resolution

Comment: нет, не медиа запросы, каюсь, я css тег дополнительно добавил, вдруг там кто то в курсе

Answer (score 0):

А, вспомнил: Client Hints. Оставлю тут если кому нибудь будет интересно.